# Why Is the DestroyWindow() Function Failing an Assert and Why is the PreTranslateMessage() Function of My ActiveX Control not Being Called?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, activex

**Question**

Why is `pWnd = (CWnd*)pMap->LookupPermanent(m_hWnd);` occasionally returning NULL in the CWnd::DestroyWindow() function causing an ASSERT statement to fail while trying to destroy a modal dialog?

Furthermore, between causing the issue and attempting to destroy the window, why does the `PreTranslateMessage()` function stop getting called?

**Initial Information**

I have an ActiveX control that implements an on screen keyboard.
This keyboard accepts both touch/click events and keystroke events from an attached hardware keyboard.
Input to the control is validated using an algorithm defined by the module that created the keyboard.

Touching the buttons on screen generates input that follows

```
OnButtonUP()->AddCharacter()->ValidateText()
```

Typing on the physical keyboard generates input that follows

```
PreTranslateMessage()->AddCharacter()->ValidateText()
```

The ValidateText() function fires an event that is handled by the module that created the keyboard.

I have added a try-catch block around the event firing to handle any errors that occur while the event is being processed.

**Confusing Behavior**

What I have found is that if an error is caused by using the USB Keyboard, when the user attempts to close the Keyboard a debug assert statement in CWnd::DestroyWindow() fails.
If the same error is caused by using the touch screen interface, the assert statement succeeds.

I have also discovered that if the error is caused using the USB keyboard, that the `PreTranslateMessage()` function for the ActiveX control stops being called. I confirmed this by setting a breakpoint on the first line of the function and spying on the messages being sent to the window. After causing the error there were still a large number of messages (mainly wm_mousemoves) but the breakpoint no longer caused the program to break.

**Source Code Snippets**

The code for firing the event is as follows:

```
try
{
    m_control->OnValidate(&text, &isValid);
}
catch (...)
{
    LOG_CRITICAL_ERROR(/*Format(*/L"Keyboard::ValidateText: Error occured while validating"/*, badText.c_str()).c_str()*/);
}
```

Where the OnValidate() function is defined as:

```
void OnValidate(BSTR* text, LONG* isValid)
{
    FireEvent(eventidOnValidate, EVENT_PARAM(VTS_PBSTR VTS_PI4), text, isValid);
}
```

The CWnd::DestroyWindow() function is (With some bits preprocessor bits removed) :

```
BOOL CWnd::DestroyWindow()
{
    CWnd* pWnd;
    CHandleMap* pMap;
    HWND hWndOrig;
    BOOL bResult;

    if ((m_hWnd == NULL) && (m_pCtrlSite == NULL))
        return FALSE;

    bResult = FALSE;
    pMap = NULL;
    pWnd = NULL;
    hWndOrig = NULL;
    if (m_hWnd != NULL)
    {
        pMap = afxMapHWND();
        ENSURE(pMap != NULL);
        pWnd = (CWnd*)pMap->LookupPermanent(m_hWnd); //<- This returns NULL before the Assert fails
        hWndOrig = m_hWnd;
    }

    if ((m_hWnd != NULL) || (m_pCtrlSite != NULL))
    {
        if (m_pCtrlSite == NULL)
            bResult = ::DestroyWindow(m_hWnd);
        else
            bResult = m_pCtrlSite->DestroyControl();
    }

    if (hWndOrig != NULL)
    {
        // Note that 'this' may have been deleted at this point,
        //  (but only if pWnd != NULL)
        if (pWnd != NULL)
        {
            // Should have been detached by OnNcDestroy
            ASSERT(pMap->LookupPermanent(hWndOrig) == NULL);
        }
        else
        {
            ASSERT(m_hWnd == hWndOrig); //<-This is the ASSERT that fails!
        // Detach after DestroyWindow called just in case
            Detach();
        }
    }

    return bResult;
}
```

From what I have been able to obtain via tracepoints, when the assert fails, `pWnd = (CWnd*)pMap->LookupPermanent(m_hWnd);` returns NULL.

Using the information from the tracepoints, the DestroyWindow() call for the Keyboard control seems to follow:

*When It Works (Error caused by touch input handled)*

- Start Destroying Keyboard: m_hWnd = NON-NULL, hWndOrig = NON-Null, pWnd = NON-NULL
- Recurse into destroying keyboard buttons: m_hWnd = NON-NULL, hWndOrig = NON-Null, pWnd = NON-NULL
- Return from destroying all buttons: m_hWnd = NULL, hWndOrig = NON-Null, pWnd = NON-NULL
- `ASSERT(pMap->LookupPermanent(hWndOrig) == NULL);` is called and succeeds.

*When It Breaks (Error caused by hardware input handled)*

- Start Destroying Keyboard: m_hWnd = NON-NULL, hWndOrig = NON-Null, pWnd = NULL
- Recurse into destroying keyboard buttons: m_hWnd = NON-NULL, hWndOrig = NON-Null, pWnd = NON-NULL
- Return from destroying all buttons: m_hWnd = NULL, hWndOrig = NON-Null, pWnd = NULL
- `ASSERT(m_hWnd == hWndOrig);` is called and fails.

Comment: The only way that assert can fire is if the value `m_hWnd` has been changed, so search your code for places where that can happen and set breakpoints on them to see what's causing it.

Comment: Is `m_pCtrlSite` NULL or not? Do you handle the `WM_NCDESTROY` message, or do you override MFC's `PostNcDestroy`?

Comment: `m_pCtrlSite` is being reported as NULL by tracepoints. I do not handle `WM_NCDESTROY` and I do not override `PostNcDestroy`

Comment: `m_pCtrlSite is being reported as NULL` Then `m_hWnd` must change at some point during `::DestroyWindow(m_hWnd);`. If not your code, most likely one of the base classes you derive from does a `Detach` in `OnNcDestroy` or `PostNcDestroy`. Like the first comment said, code inspection and debugging are your best hopes.

Comment: In my case, I had created a cwnd derived class which I was creating dynamically with new. I was then trying to delete this object from some other thread. Now CWND constructor calls DestroyWindow() which calls afxMapHWND(), which in turn calls `AfxGetModuleThreadState()`. `AfxGetModuleThreadState()` manages thread specific state (thread local storage), thus when called from another thread was returning incorrect data (all members null). A better approach is to use PostQuitMessage().

Comment: Some links related to my comment.
http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?272642-Creating-a-CWnd-at-runtime
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/dynamic-object-creation?view=vs-2019
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn017-destroying-window-objects?view=vs-2019
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/run-time-object-model-services?view=vs-2019#declare_dynamic

Comment: `A thread cannot use DestroyWindow to destroy a window created by a different thread.` from DestroyWindow() doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-destroywindow